# Hiding a window when opening it from bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to **make a bash script to run another bash script in a new terminal window**.

I used the command:

```
sudo gnome-terminal -e "bash file_name.sh"
```

This works as I want it to. 
But I want to hide the second terminal window that opens. I have tried running in background using `&` but it does not work like I want it to. I want the terminal window to be hidden.

Is there any way I could set the terminal window to not show up?

Comment: Could you explain why you need another window, but that should be hidden? That seems contre-intuitive, and there might be easier solutions to your problem. Also, what do you mean by hidden? Minimized?

Comment: I would like to point you in the direction of X resources which might allow you to assign a class (or what it's called) to the new gnome-terminal window and specify either it being minimized or at a position/size that makes it "invisible" - can't post exact answer though, and adressing the reason why you want to do it at all may be more efficient - Ah, I just see you can specify a geometry for the gnome-terminal with `--geometry=GEOMETRY (See X manpage)` which would allow you to position/size the window far out of user's way

Comment: @Aaron I have a second code that connects me to a server, its actually an expect script(for username and password), but I asked in case of bash, cause then the question would be more general. The expect script is to be opened into new terminal, as I can't execute further commands in my original terminal, cause I have to remain connected to the server while I execute other commands in my original shell.

Answer (score 2):

Well for what i have understood about Linux and the "&" optional command, it's already that what you call hidden. You may miss "disown" command so you can run the code in background while being able to close the shell.

> start it in the background:
>
> ```
> command &
> ```
>
> then run:
>
> ```
> disown
> ```
>
> and close the terminal.
>
> You can stop a foregrounded application with Ctrl+z, then start it in
>   the background (foreground) with the bg (fg) command.

You can read the source here on a Ubuntu Forum: ["How to hide terminal window?"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1451311&p=9102544#post9102544)

Answer (score 1):

You could use nohup to run the process in background:

```
$ sudo nohup ./file_name.sh &
```

There will be a new process to execute `file_name.sh`, output will be written to `nohup.out`.